# Reproduce a datset to different format in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset `Data` like below:

```
dput(Data)
structure(list(FN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "20131202-0985 ", class = "factor"), Values = structure(c(1L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("|639778|21|NANYANG CIRCLE|103.686721631628|1.34640300329567", 
"|8121|B01|SOMERSET STN", "|96942883", "|SN30|SMRT\n", "CENTRAL", 
"FOUR SEASONS HOTEL", "HOTEL", "IKEA", "nanyang avenue"), class = "factor"), 
    IND = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("BN", 
    "BR", "BS", "LOC", "PN", "RN"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("FN", 
"Values", "IND"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

[image]
I wanted the above dataset to be converted as in the below format as a Data Frame(`out_data`).
Presently my `Data` has 3 columns - and need to covert these into 16 columns in below format.
I need to rehape my input - to exactly given in the screenshot as data frame.
I cannot change the below structure -

```
colnames(out_data) <- ("FN","H_BLK","S_N/R_N","B_N","FL_N","U_N","PC","XC","YC","BS","BRF","LCT_DEC","BRN","BO  PN","S_TY_CD")
```

[image]

The Multiple value columns in the inputnand are always in the below Format:

- `|639778|21|NANYANG CIRCLE|103.686721631628|1.34640300329567` -
  `|PC|H_BLK|S_N/R_N|XC|YC`
- `|8121|B01|SOMERSET STN` -> `|BS|BRF|LCT_DEC`
- `|SN30|SMRT` ------> `|BRN|BO`

If the

```
IND =LOC - then |PC|H_BLK|S_N/R_N|XC|YC`  get updated with S_TY_CD=LOC
IND= BN - then B_N column should be updated with S_TY_CD=BN
IND= RN - then _N/R_N column should be updated with S_TY_CD=RN
IND= BS then `|BS|BRF|LCT_DEC` should be updated with S_TY_CD=BS
IND= BR then `|BRN|BO` should be updated with S_TY_CD=BR
IND= PN then PN with S_TY_CD=PN
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: How are you supposed to know what columns those multi-value fields are supposed to go in? On the first line, how did you know to put 103.68 in XC?

Comment: `|639778|21|NANYANG CIRCLE|103.686721631628|1.34640300329567` is in this format `|PC|H_BLK|S_N/R_N|XC|YC` always and similarly `|8121|B01|SOMERSET STN` is in `|BS|BRF|LCT_DEC` and `|SN30|SMRT` is always in this format `|BRN|BO`

Comment: So this image is your only documentation of the file format?

Comment: Yes it is the only format - i have updated the question.All other values like `FL_N`,`U_N` will be null.Thanks

Comment: Have you at least created an inefficient way to do it yet? Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I have updated the question - i am trying with `If-else` loop to update new dataframe

Comment: @MrFlick But i am not able to get in the format i wanted

Comment: If you post your R code, someone might be able to help you with the parts that don't work. You've written out a lot of the logic so it shouldn't be that hard to translate into code, but you can't expect people to do everything for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one method of transformation. First I define some helper functions for the various sub problems.

```
#define  out cols
outcols<-c("FN", "H_BLK", "S_N/R_N", "B_N", "FL_N", "U_N", "PC", 
    "XC", "YC", "BS", "BRF", "LCT_DEC", "BRN","BO","PN","S_TY_CD")

#identify parts for each compound value
namevals <- function(ind, vals) {
    names<-if (ind=="LOC") {
        c("PC","H_BLK","S_N/R_N","XC","YC")
    } else if (ind=="BN") {
        c("B_N")
    } else if (ind=="RN") {
        c("S_N/R_N")
    } else if (ind=="BS") {
        c("BS","BRF","LCT_DEC")
    } else if (ind=="BR") {
        c("BRN","BO")
    } else if (ind=="PN") {
        c("PN")
    }
    stopifnot(length(names)==length(vals))
    stopifnot(all(names %in% outcols))
    names(vals)<-names
    vals
}

#add missing values for row
fillrow <- function(nvals) {
    r<-rep(NA, length(outcols))
    r[match(names(nvals), outcols)]<-nvals
    r
}
```

Now I apply these to each row of the data with `mapply` to return a character vector. Here we make sure to split the "values" column on the pipe and remove the leading pipe.

```
#combine rows into character matrix
dt<-mapply(function(fn,vals,ind){   
    x<-c(FN=fn,namevals(ind, vals), "S_TY_CD"=ind)
    fillrow(x)
  }, 
  as.character(Data$FN), 
  strsplit(gsub("^\\|","",as.character(Data$Values)),"|", fixed=T), 
  as.character(Data$IND)
)
```

Finally we tidy the data up so it can be written out to a file with `write.table`. Note that all missing values are true R `NA` values. In the `write.table`, you can set `na = ""` if you'd rather they print out as blank values than the default "NA" value.

```
#turn matrix into data.frame with proper names
dd<-data.frame(unname(t(dt)), stringsAsFactors=F)
names(dd)<-outcols
dd
```

Comment: S_TY_CD is not populated with the Indicator column